# Reduce context switch

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, query-optimization, context-switch

**Question:**

Oracle SQL - I have 2 select queries(Say SQ1 & SQ2). Both SQ1 & SQ2 select an ID value, but with different join conditions, diff tables & where conditions.

scenario 1: if the SQ1 returns 1 row, do an update to a table with the result of the select statement.
If the SQ1 returns 0 or more than 1 rows, control should go to scenario 2.

scenario 2: if the SQ2 returns 1 row, do an update to a table with the result of the SQ2 statement.
If SQ2 returns 0 or >1 results, call another package procedure.

How to have minimum context switches to the DB?

**How I have coded:**

```
select count(*) into v_count from table; ---SQ1
case if v_count=1 ...then do this...
Else
  select count(*) into v_count2 from table; ---SQ2  
     --2nd case starts here
     case if 
         v_count2=1 ...then do this...
         else call package.procedure. 
     end case;
end case;
```

**Requirement**

Have minimum call to the database. Reduce context switches.

Answer (score 3):

> SQ2 is the same select statement as SQ1, but with additional where conditions.

You can do just one statement like this

```
SELECT 
   count(*),
   count( case when ... /*additional where condition for SQ2 */ then 1 end )
INTO v_count, v_count2
FROM table
```

and then do a cascade of IF-THEN-ELSIF statements:

```
IF v_count = 1 THEN 
   ..do this...
ELSIF v_count2=1  THEN 
   ...do that...
ELSE 
   call package.procedure. 
END IF;
```

In this way you save 1 context switch and 1 table scan.

Comment: Apologies. I have updated the question. 

Both SQ1 & SQ2 select an ID value, but with different join conditions, diff tables & where conditions.

Comment: Good answer, but are context switches from the PL/SQL->SQL engine really that expensive?  My understanding has always been to watch for SQL->PL/SQL switches, but that PL/SQL->SQL switches were well optimized in Oracle.  I suspect the OP is unnecessarily complicating his code with this optimization.

Comment: @Matthew McPeak you need to test to know exact values, but a query with context swiches can be even 30~50 times slower than simple SQL (50 times --> 5000%).

Comment: @krokodilko Those are SQL->PL/SQL context switches and the need to limit those is well known.  But the guidance I've seen has been that PL/SQL->SQL (i.e., calling a SQL statement from a PL/SQL block) context switches are better optimized and less problematic.

Answer (score 2):

Well, having no other information, something like this should work:

```
update t
    set col = coalesce( (<SQL1>), (<SQL2>)
    where (select count(*) from <sql1>) = 1 or
          (select count(*) from <sql2) = 1;
```

That said, I would probably fix your filtering statements so they return either 0 or 1 rows, never more than 1.

Comment: Thanks. But the table is configured to have multiple results(more than 1 records). Hence it is an expected scenario.

Comment: How can we put SQL statements in Coalesce? It doesn't work for me

Comment: @Natty . . . You need an extra set of parentheses, as you would for any scalar subquery.

Comment: --This is the test code I did
DECLARE
n int;

BEGIN
n := coalesce ((select 1 from dual),2);
dbms_output.put_line(n);
end;

Comment: @Natty . . . You don't need PL/SQL for this.  This is just a single SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN code like this, but this code will be hard to understand and even harder to maintain. But if it is about milliseconds, I have seen worse code. And surprise, depending on how often which scenario will occur, this might not even be the most performant way.

```
declare
  result1 varchar2(2000);
  result2 varchar2(2000);
begin
  -- a single select gets the all you need from both tables
  -- it has the number of rows and the correct column  value
  -- if there are 0 or >1 rows, you'll ignore the column anyway
  select 
    (select to_char (count (1)) || 'x' || max(<column1>) from tab1e1),
    (select to_char (count (1)) || 'x' || max(<column2>) from table2)
  into
    result1,
    result2
  from dual;

  -- check the number of rows, if there is one, result will start with '1x'
  if to_number (substr (result1, 1, instr (result1, 'x') - 1)) = 1 then
    null; -- update table1 with substr (result1, instr (result1, 'x') + 1)
  elsif to_number (substr (result2, 1, instr (result2, 'x') - 1)) = 1 then
    null; -- update table2 with substr (result2, instr (result2, 'x') + 1)
  else
    null; -- call package
  end if;
end;
```